# Netbeans code prediction

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using Netbeans for couple of days to learn Java. I have used visual studio before for c# and it was really good at predicting but I can not find something for netbeans. I found something like ctrl and space for code completion but its really annoying to use them everytime. Rather I would expect something like visual studio. Let me know if there is any plugin or built in option for code prediction in netbeans.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans is a good IDE but for java i prefer IntelliJ idea there is a community version free of charge you could try it, link below.

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Comment: +1, If you want more intelligent code completion IntelliJ is the way to go, and since your just starting in Java, this shouldn't be much of a change.

Comment: Yes, the above link is to IntelliJ Idea, which is a Java IDE

Comment: I never used IntelliJ idea, the community edition is a good option to work with Java EE, Hibernate, Primefaces, Spring, Maven, etc.?